# Filter sequence items in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, filter, sequence

I have a tensor of allowed items

```
index = tf.constant([61, 215, 23, 18, 241, 125])
```

and need to remove items from input sequence batches that are not in `index`.

```
seq = tf.constant(
    [
        [ 18, 241,   0,   0],
        [125,  61,  23, 241],
        [ 23,  92,  18,   0],
        [  5,  61, 215,  18],
    ]
)
```

After the calculation in this case I need

```
result_needed = tf.constant(
    [
        [ 18, 241,   0,   0],
        [125,  61,  23, 241],
        [ 23,  18,   0,   0],
        [ 61, 215,  18,   0],
    ]
)
```

I cannot do this in Python because this calculation happens during predictions. Also note that while item IDs here are small, solution needs to deal with numbers from 1 to 2^40.

**Answer**

After some serious pondering time, I came up with the following:

```
idx_range = tf.reshape(tf.range(seq.shape[-2]), [-1, 1])
idx_tile = tf.tile(idx_range, [1, seq.shape[-2].value])
idx_flat = tf.reshape(idx_tile, [-1])

truth_value = tf.equal(index, tf.expand_dims(seq, -1))
one_hot = tf.to_float(truth_value)

ones = tf.nn.top_k(tf.reduce_sum(one_hot, -1), seq.shape[-1]).indices
ones_flat = tf.reshape(ones, [-1])
ones_idx = tf.reshape(
    tf.stack([idx_flat, ones_flat], axis=1),
    tf.concat([seq.shape, [2]], axis=0)
)

tf.gather_nd(seq, ones_idx)
```

This is not exactly what I said I needed, but actually got me close enough. Instead of the output replacing the blacklisted items with 0, it moves them to the end. If you needed them gone, I'm sure there's a method to remove them, but I'm not looking into it. Apologies.